# ajax code cannot access json responds from php

Tags: php, json, jquery

this is my ajax call

```
<script src = "js/jquery.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#DepartmentNameDropdown').change(function(){

        $('#DepartmentName').attr('value', document.getElementById("DepartmentNameDropdown").options[document.getElementById("DepartmentNameDropdown").selectedIndex].text);                                 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:8081/crownregency/getInfo.php",
        data: {id : $('#DepartmentNameDropdown').val()}, //data: {status: status, name: name},
        success:function(data){
            $('#DepartmentDescription').attr('value', data.Desc);
        }           
    });
});                    
});
$('#DepartmentName').attr('value', $('#DepartmentNameDropdown').text());    

</script>
```

this is my getinfo.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("jkings");
$value = $_POST['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM department WHERE dept_ID = $value");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$desc = $row['dept_desc'];
$mission = $row['dept_mission'];
$struct = array('Desc' => '$desc', 'Mission' => '$mission');
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $value;

echo json_encode($struct);
//echo $row['dept_desc'];
?>
```

I do not know where in the code i made a mistake but it seems i can't access the json responds. i have tried different ways to this, i am still learning this ajax and json so it is hard for me to see where i made a mistake

Comment: first correct  this line `$struct = array('Desc' => $desc, 'Mission' => $mission);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you might have to change

> ```
> $('#DepartmentDescription').attr('value', data.Desc);
> ```

into

> ```
> $('#DepartmentDescription').attr('value', data['Desc']);
> ```

Also,

> $struct = array('Desc' => '$desc', 'Mission' => '$mission');

should be changed to

> $struct = array('Desc' => $desc, 'Mission' => $mission);

Answer (score 0):

your javascript seem to be fine i will suggest this to detect where the problem might lie

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:8081/crownregency/getInfo.php",
    data: {id : $('#DepartmentNameDropdown').val()}, //data: {status: status, name: name},
    success:function(data){
         alert(data.Desc)// should alert [object object] if all is well with your php code
        $('#DepartmentDescription').attr('value', data.Desc);
    }           
});
```

i really doubt it but could be a case sensitivity issue so maybe change

```
dataType:'json' to dataType:'JSON'
```

also if you are using chrome use developers tool to see if there are javascript errors (develop for safari)